# changing value of cell based on value of another cell

Tags: vba, excel

i have sheet with 2000+ rows, in cell S i have some value, based on cell S  i need to change value in cell V

for example if value of cell S is < 3552 than cell V= 241 else V=240

code need to check every row

tnx

Comment: why not just in `V1` use formula: `=IF(S1<3552,241,240)`?

Comment: need to be done in vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> need to be done in vba

Try this one:

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    'change Sheet1 to suit
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'find lastrow in column S
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row
        'change V1 to, say, V2 if your data starts from V2
        With Range("V1:V" & lastrow)
            'calculate result with formula
            .Formula = "=IF(S1<3552,241,240)" 'change S1 to, say, S2 if your data starts from S2
            'rewrite formula with values
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: what about if i want to use 2 cells for criteria, how to do that. for example i need to check value for cell S and cell L and then to give value to cell V

Comment: in that case just modify formula in line `.Formula = "=IF(S1<3552,241,240)"`. Say, if you'd like `V1` be 241 if (`S1<3552` and `L1=4`) then use `.Formula = "=IF(AND(L1=4,S1<3552),241,240)"`

Comment: i tried to use  "=IF(AND(L2<>marko test,S2<3552),241,240)" and i get #name

Comment: try this one: `.Formula = "=IF(AND(L2<>""marko test"",S2<3552),241,240)"`

Comment: what is your new problem?

Comment: im using 3 valuse for cell V 254, 240 and 241. 254 is using if L= marko test all the time, 240 if L<> marko test and S>3552 and 241 id L<> marko test and S<352 :S

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48997/discussion-between-simoco-and-marko-pantic)