# Directly fill result of a formula in excel using vba efficiently

Tags: vba, excel

I am filling up values in 90000 rows by using a formula as given below.
However, I need to replace the formula result with static text. As of now the formula is being filled for a Range of cells as below.

```
Range(Cells(2, 18), Cells(LRow, 18)).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = _
    "=IF(OR(Macro.xls!ColorIndex(RC[" & colDiff & "])=3,Macro.xls!ColorIndex(RC[19])=3,Macro.xls!ColorIndex(RC[20])=3))
```

And am converting the result to static text one by one as below.

```
Range(Cells(2, currCol - 2), Cells(LRow, currCol)).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Selection
    c.Value = c.Value
Next
```

This seems to be very slow, Is there a way to directly fill in the values in the cell than filling the formula, calculating result and converting to text?

If not, Is there an efficient way of replacing the formula result to static text.

Note:

1. Am aware the code block is not using with reference, would be changing that later.
2. Copying the range of cells programatically and pasting the values doesnt work as there are hidden cells.

Comment: you could simply use single line: `Selection.Value=Selection.Value`. You can see how I do it in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180725/changing-value-of-cell-based-on-value-of-another-cell/22180844#22180844).

Comment: Fills the same value across all cells. 
Without `.Value = .Value` the formula result shows up as expected.

Comment: try to add `Selecion.Calculate` just before `.Value = .Value`